# AEM dispatcher not loading the html page on first hit

Tags: aem

[image]When we are trying to access a page which is not already cached in dispatcher it show entire html on screen and doesn't render it as page .
Attached image show how dom section on first load.

On subsequent request we are able to see entire pages and all html,css, images, js are loaded correctly.

Are we missing any configuration here.

Comment: Is your dispatcher passing through all the headers? It looks like the page is returned as text rather than HTML. If your publisher displays the page properly compare the headers between the publisher and dispatcher and pass through the doctype and other relevant headers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure your dispatcher to pass through the headers for a HTML page to be displayed correctly. HTML won't be parsed correctly by some browsers if the headers are incorrect.

This can be done by specifying the passthrough headers in the `/clientheaders` section. A sample configuration will look as below:

```
/clientheaders
{
   "referer"
   "user-agent"
   "authorization"
   "from"
   "content-type"
   "content-length"
   "accept-charset"
   "accept-encoding"
   "accept-language"
   "accept"
   "host"
   "cookie"
}
```

See https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-config.html for more details.

You will also need to setup the `ModMimeUsePathInfo` for your Apache web server as describer over [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-install.html#Apache%20Web%20Server%20-%20Configure%20Apache%20Web%20Server%20for%20Dispatcher).

Dispatcher depends on the [mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html) Apache module to correctly identify the documents to cache. This is one of the minimum configuration that is required on the httpd server for correct functioning of the Dispatcher module.

A simple configuration to enable mod_mime will be as below:

```
<Directory />
   <IfModule disp_apache2.c>
      SetHandler dispatcher-handler
      ModMimeUsePathInfo On
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: We have allowed all the header as of now and  doctype is also set to html "<!DOCTYPE html>"
/clientheaders
      {
          "*"
      }

Comment: Updated answer for your problem.